# Showing specific business card from fusion tables to google site

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables, controlpanel

I am creating a Google site that has a user login information at the beginning of it. Once the user logs in, it shows a profile of his information retrieved from a business card in a fusion table. The Issue I am facing is that how can I compare the column filter that has the email name with the email inserted to retrieve the data in a business card layout into this Google site.

Is there some kind of a function in Google apps script that retrieve the username inserted from the control panel so that I can compare it with the one inserted in an 'Email' column in the fusion table.

I have searched in the [fusiontables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) but could not find anything straight to the point I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy a web app as an [Apps Script Gadget in Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets) to [run as the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#permissions), then you can use [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser%28%29) in your script to get the information about the user logged in.